# Is Quartz scheduler no longer useful with Spring from 3.0 version onwards?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

Spring's internal scheduling capability as of Spring 3, includes support for cron-type expressions, and this is very similar to Quartz's cron trigger.

Is there any reason why one would want to integrate Quartz with Spring?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler

Comment: And you post this after I was told to add Quartz in a system that already uses Spring... T_T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will need quarz for example:

- if you need to add new jobs at runtime, or
- if you need to change the interval (cron expression) at runtime,
- if you need statistics about the jobs,
- ...

in general: if you need more than simply runing a method at fixed time.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, Spring scheduling doesn't support persistent job stores, recovering misfires due to downtime, or clustered schedulers. Quartz has had all of this for years.